# Wrong Color in Smoke Simulation?

Tags: color, smoke-simulation

I make a simply smoke simulation in Blender 3.6 with one color at the beginning. But already in the "wireframe" and "solid" view the color changes during the simulation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This has then of course also a negtive effect on the material and render view. I changed nearly all values but unfotunately no change. Does anyone know what setting is wrong? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Just found the reason, although I thought tried it already. For who is interested, deselect "Is Planar", than it seems working correctly. But it's not really understandable to me...